# Application crashes without showing any Dialog

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, huawei-mobile-services

I am using Huawei Mate 10 with 8.0 OS. The problem I'm facing is it doesn't show any kind of app crashing dialog. When any run time error occurs, Activity closes automatically without showing any crash dialog in this situation all the crash logs are removed in my Android studio Logcat and I'm not able to catch the error. Is there any way to hold crash dialog because ANR dialog does not clear the logcat till i close dialog.
Thankyou...

Comment: Debug your app. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/

Comment: this will help you  **[Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)**

Comment: When debugger is not attached to android device. Here I want Crash dialogue, where I can also report the crash.

Comment: Use Fabric crash report library or any other crash report library. you will get email whenever your app will crash

Comment: run app in debug mode and create a breakpoints on create method or first entry of code.

Answer (score 1):

> in this situation all the crash logs are removed in my Android studio Logcat and I'm not able to catch the error

It's annoying behaviour but they are not actually removed, only hidden. To see them after the crash, set <kbd>Show only selected application</kbd> on the Logcat panel to <kbd>No filters</kbd> and set <kbd>Verbose</kbd> dropdown to <kbd>Error</kbd> to easily find the correct logs